# Popover dynamic position isn't updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using UI-Bootstrap as part of my angular application.

I added some simple popover which loads an HTML template file.

The popover position set fine but once I try to resize the window the popover location is not getting updated. However, if I close the popover and open it again, the new position is calculated.

Any idea what can cause the popover not to calculate the new position or any suggestions how to solve this?

Simple code:

```
<div id="some-wrapper">
    <div popover-is-open="isOpen" 
         uib-popover-template="history" 
         popover-placement="left">History
    </div>
</div>
```

I've spent 2 days on looking for a solution but with no success.

The strange thing is that in some other angular applications which use the same UI-Bootstrap version, the position is getting update during window resize.

Comment: You need to bind a positioning method to the window's resize event. Have you done that? If so, it's probably not a problem with Bootstrap, it's likely that you have JS that is conflicting. Do you receive any console errors?

Comment: I need positioning function for for the popover ?  I don't have in any of my applications but in the older application the position is getting update... I don't see any console error in my new application. Can you provide example for the positioning function ?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information to reproduce or help debug the issue, unfortunately. Try to provide more information so we can help you.

Comment: Yeah , I thought what kind of information I can provide more but unfortunately I don't see any other relevant information and sharing the full code is not an option.

Comment: try using `popover-placement="auto"`

Comment: Same. Its for auto select in which side to place the popover but.

Answer (score 0):

The popover component is built from the [tooltip](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js) component.  There is no support for repositioning the tooltip or popover on window resize or scroll.

Comment: So I have no idea how in my other app while changing the window size i can see the popover move together with the label his attached with . Also while using the inspector i can see the position values (left ,top) being changed dynamically during the window resize ... so its really not clear what is the difference .